# How do I access *unsaved* Excel workbooks in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have an external process that generates multiple work sheets. The process cannot be modified. 
The process that generates them does not save them. It leaves then as individual Excel 2010 work books: Book1, Book2, …, Book14.

I want to have a macro open each one, in sequence, but can’t get my macro to see them.

This won’t work:

```
excel.application.Workbooks("Bookx").Activate
```

This doesn't work

```
excel.application.Workbooks(x).sheets(1).Activate
```

My macro seems to see only the active workbook; it doesn't realize the other workbooks exist.

What is the correct method for opening up an external workbook/sheet
that is not saved to a file?

Comment: With Excel 2016, this is not an issue.        
    Workbooks(x).sheets(1).Activate  works fine. it is **Only** with Excel 2010 that this method doesn't work.

Comment: worksheets or workbooks?

Answer (score 0):

Open an immediate window in the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) editor.

Type in ?excel.Application.Workbooks.Count  If it correctly prints the number of workbooks you have open, you will be able use `excel.application.Workbooks("Bookx").Activate` (I just tried it on 2010). (`excel.Application.Workbooks(2).sheets(2).activate` also works.)

It won't work though if this external process is opening the new workbooks in separate instances. If that's the case, they are completely (by design) separate from each-other and you won't be able to use VBA to refer to them.

Once in the correct workbook, in the debug window use

`?excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count` to determine if the correct number of sheets are being reported. If they are, simply refer to each one by using `activeworkbook.sheets(x)`.  If the debug window reports the wrong number of sheets, I think you have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution seems to be using the **GetObject** method. This worked very nicely for me:

```
Number_of_Books = 10
For PTR = 1 To Number_of_Books
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set xlApp = GetObject("Book" & PTR).Application
        xlApp.Application.Workbooks("Book" & PTR).Sheets("Table").Activate
        xlApp.Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
        xlApp.Application.Workbooks("Book" & PTR).Sheets("Table").Select
        xlApp.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=DIRNAME_DATA & "Book" & PTR & ".xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        xlApp.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        x = x + 1
Next
```